# side modal full height header ,body and footer not equal

Tags: css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

i created a full height side modal it has a long content 
inside the modal body but when i run it the header and body and
the footer is not equal i dont know if placing a scrollspy on html body
tag will fix it  , Hope you can help me fix it. thanks.

here is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade right" id="modalPoll" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
      data-backdrop="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-full-height modal-right modal-notify modal-info" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <!--Header-->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <p class="heading lead">Feedback request
            </p>
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">×</span>
            </button>
          </div>
      <!--Body-->
          <div class="modal-body" >
            <div class="text-center">
              <i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-4x mb-3 animated rotateIn"></i>
              <p>
                <strong>Your opinion matters</strong>
              </p>
              <p>Have some ideas how to improve our product?
                <strong></strong>Give us your feedback.</strong>
              </p>
            </div>
            <hr>
       <!-- Radio -->
            <p class="text-center">
              <strong>Your rating</strong>
            </p>
            <div class="form-check mb-4">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="group1" type="radio" id="radio-179" value="option1" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-179">Very good</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check mb-4">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="group1" type="radio" id="radio-279" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-279">Good</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check mb-4">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="group1" type="radio" id="radio-379" value="option3">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-379">Mediocre</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check mb-4">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="group1" type="radio" id="radio-479" value="option4">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-479">Bad</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check mb-4">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="group1" type="radio" id="radio-579" value="option5">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-579">Very bad</label>
        </div>
            <!-- Radio -->
        <p class="text-center">
              <strong>What could we improve?</strong>
            </p>
            <!--Basic textarea-->
            <div class="md-form">
              <textarea type="text" id="form79textarea" class="md-textarea form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
              <label for="form79textarea">Your message</label>
            </div>
            </div>
          <!--Footer-->
          <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Send
              <i class="fa fa-paper-plane ml-1"></i>
            </a>
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

here is my current ouput :
[image: this is the header]
[image: this is the footer]

Comment: do you use bootstrap 4?

Comment: yes i use bootsrap 4

Comment: by the way you have unneccesery `</strong>` in  `<strong></strong>Give us your feedback.</strong>`

Comment: can you show the button that open the model

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPoll">Launch modal</button>

Comment: you want the header be `fixed` or make scroll to `model`?

Comment: i tried the fixed header using height with 300px; and it fixed the header but the footer goes up.

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 0):

Use `sticky-top` to `modal-header`

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPoll">Launch modal</button>

<div class="modal fade right" id="modalPoll" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="myModal"
      data-backdrop="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-full-height modal-right modal-notify modal-info" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <!--Header-->
          <div class="modal-header sticky-top bg-primary">
            <p class="heading lead">Feedback request
            </p>
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">×</span>
            </button>
          </div>
      <!--Body-->
          <div class="modal-body" >
            <div class="text-center">
              <i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-4x mb-3 animated rotateIn"></i>
              <p>
                <strong>Your opinion matters</strong>
              </p>
              <p>Have some ideas how to improve our product?
                <strong>Give us your feedback.</strong>
              </p>
            </div>
            <hr>
       <!-- Radio -->
            <p class="text-center">
              <strong>Your rating</strong>
            </p>
            <div class="form-check mb-4">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="group1" type="radio" id="radio-179" value="option1" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-179">Very good</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check mb-4">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="group1" type="radio" id="radio-279" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-279">Good</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check mb-4">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="group1" type="radio" id="radio-379" value="option3">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-379">Mediocre</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check mb-4">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="group1" type="radio" id="radio-479" value="option4">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-479">Bad</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check mb-4">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="group1" type="radio" id="radio-579" value="option5">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio-579">Very bad</label>
        </div>
            <!-- Radio -->
        <p class="text-center">
              <strong>What could we improve?</strong>
            </p>
            <!--Basic textarea-->
            <div class="md-form">
              <textarea type="text" id="form79textarea" class="md-textarea form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
              <label for="form79textarea">Your message</label>
            </div>
            </div>
          <!--Footer-->
          <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Send
              <i class="fa fa-paper-plane ml-1"></i>
            </a>
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: don't you see the header is `fixed`?

Comment: i  run your snippet and yes i see the header fixed but when i tried it on my code it did not the header its still the same, btw im using material design bootstrap

Comment: what do you when you say scroll model ?

Comment: to scroll only the model not the page

Comment: can you show me some example ? the first one is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Replace your modal-content div by:

```
<div class="modal-content py-0" style="max-height: 100%; overflow-y: auto;">...</div>
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some explanation as to why this answers OPs question. What does it change? How does that resolve the asked question?